# How to Keep the data that user entered in textbox even after submit button is clicked and even if page is reloaded

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to keep the data in a text box after submit and inserted into db.
even if i refresh the page data should not change or empty

here is my code

```
<tr class="form-field1">
<th valign="top" scope="row">
<label for="approved_admin"><?php _e('Collaboration Admin', 'custom_table_example')?></label>
</th>
<td>
<input id="approved_admin" name="approved_admin" type="email"  value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['approved_admin'])?>"size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Admin Email', 'custom_table_example')?>"  required>
</td>
</tr>
```

if i do this data will be there if i reload empty text box will be shown.I need to make this readonly and onload same text should be there.

Form

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__))?>"/>
<?php /* NOTICE: here we storing id to determine will be item added or updated */ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $item['sid'] ?>"/>
<div class="metabox-holder" id="poststuff">
<div id="post-body">
<div id="post-body-content">
<?php /* And here we call our custom meta box */ ?>
<?php do_meta_boxes('Settings', 'normal', $item); ?>
<input   type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'custom_table_example')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit"  / >
<input   type="submit" value="<?php _e('Edit', '')?>" id="edit" class="button-primary" name="edit"  / >
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I tried doing

```
<input type="email" name="approved_admin" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['approved_admin'])) { echo $_POST['approved_admin']; }  ?>">
```

and also

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" <?php isset($approved_admin) ? echo 'readonly' : ''; ?> >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save data after page reload a lot of ways like... `Session , cookie, get , post`. After this value get by `isset` and `echo` .

In your case Post method used..

Try this working fine all thing

```
<input type="text" name="country" value=" <?php echo isset($_POST['country']) ?  $_POST['country'] : ''; ?>" <?php echo isset($_POST['country']) ?  'readonly' : ''; ?> >
```

You just put field name in `isset()`;

Comment: What issue you get cleraly explain... Because its working fine everywhere.

Comment: when i enter the mail id click on save ,it should be in readonly format,and if i reload page it should remain the same

Comment: Try just simple form like.. <form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="country" value=" <?php echo isset($_POST['country']) ?  $_POST['country'] : ''; ?>" <?php echo isset($_POST['country']) ?  'readonly' : ''; ?> ><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>  Try this , its working or not for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax. Have a try for this.

```
<input type="text" id="to_date" name="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['to_date']) ? $_POST['to_date'] : '' ?>" />
```

The name of the input type has to be mentioned in the **isset()** condition.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the user's input in that POST value, or it is liable for Cross Site Scripting.

Comment: if i refresh the page data will be erased and will be empty

Comment: If you are using same page post and the data will remain in the entered manner.

Comment: provide an action as `<form method="POST" if="form" action=""></form>`. Since some browser are not supporting without action=""

Comment: i gave action as #

Comment: still if i refresh the page it shows empty field to enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121311/discussion-between-jmr-and-naresh-kumar-p).